# Angular grouped array slice in *ngfor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, types, ngfor

I have two arrays in one array item and inside one  i only need to show 10 items
my array is like this

```
this.groupedData = [{
        "title": true,
        "name": "related",
        "list": [{
                "id": 30,
                "text": "CIGA",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            },

            {
                "id": 34,
                "text": "GAP",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 35,
                "text": "LEVIS",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 36,
                "text": "MANGO",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 37,
                "text": "Nigel",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "Id": 39,
                "text": "Test",
                "related": true,
                "list": [

                ]
            }
        ],
        "selected": false,
        "disabled": false
    },
    {
        "title": true,
        "name": "unrelated",
        "list": [{
                "id": 29,
                "text": "Burger",
                "related": false,
                "list": [

                ]
            }

        ],
        "selected": false,
        "disabled": false
    }
]
```

i am looping list array and need to set only 10 items in  one `<Ul>` tag list items in both arrays and need to loop 10 item list `<ul>` according to that `optionColumnLength` has number of columns need to show and that array looks like  `[0, 1, 2]` html is look like this

```
<div *ngFor="let colindex of optionColumnLength">
       <ul class="item2">
           <div *ngFor="let group of groupedData let j = index;">
               <label>{{group.name}}</label>
               <li *ngFor="let item of group.list | slice: colindex * 10: colindex * 10 + 10 | multiSelectFilter:filter;  let i = index;" (click)="onItemClick($event,item)" class="multiselect-item-checkbox">
                   <div class="dd-list-row">
                       <div class="dd-list-block">
                           <input type="checkbox" aria-label="multiselect-item" [class.disabled-selected]="disabled"
                                  [checked]="isSelected(item)" [disabled]="disabled || (isLimitSelectionReached() && !isSelected(item)) || item.isDisabled" />
                           <div>{{item.text}}</div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <li class='no-data' *ngIf="_data.length == 0">
                   <h5>{{_settings.noDataAvailablePlaceholderText}}</h5>
               </li>
           </div>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

this is the current view and i only need to show 10 items in one column and if more than that it need to show in another 10 item column
[current view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGDpi.png)

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is/what you're trying to achieve. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmm6sy)'s a StackBlitz to help you reproduce your issue.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Nitika i only need to show 10 items in the one column

Comment: @Viqas I updated stackblitz. i only need to show only 10 items in one column if more than that it need to add another column mean  `<ul>`

Comment: You've used `slice` in `<li>` element, it'll give you 10 elements only.